# Is there a standard interface guaranteeing void main(String[] args)?

Tags: java, interface

I'm fairly new to java and looking for an interface that simply guarantees that a main(args) exists -- e.g. suitable for running from the command line with "java classname arg1 ... argN " -- without doing more.

More formally, I think that this would suffice:

```
public interface App {

public static void main(String[] args);

}
```

Is there such an interface in the standard libraries that are usually found in a JDK?

I couldn't find a formal entry for "Application" or "App" in the Nutshell book nor does googling "java interface main" turn up anything useful.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hmm...looks like I've confused a class vs an instance.  Perhaps a better question would have been -- Is there an abstract class in the standard class hierarchy which defines only a static main() from which I should extend all of my classes that have a main() ?

Comment: still, it does seem like there should be something like this.

Comment: Java in a Nutshell, 5th ed., p. 135 interfaces.... have only abstract methods... and an abstract method can not be static.

Comment: Once upon a time I remember "public class MyApp extends Application {..." as being in the "Hello, World" example of a java book I put down.  Came away with the impression that to get anything done in Java you had to memorize some giant class hierarchy. I wonder if Application was standard back then?

Comment: I think your architecture might need some re-thinking. All the main() is suppose to do is kick off the real work. Why would you want this?

Comment: @Paul: You may be thinking of [`Applet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html), which you needed to use if you wanted your Java code to appear in a web browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Interfaces can't define static methods.  There is no interface that defines a main method.

Answer (score 3):

As others said, you can't have abstract static methods. I'll try to explain *why*.

A static member is attached to one class only - the one that it's defined in. It can't be inherited. The problem is, the Java syntax makes it *look* like you can inherit it; if a parent class A has a static method f(), and you write a subclass B, then you can call the method like this: `B.f()`. However, you're actually calling `A.f()`. This is a meaningless distinction, unless you do something like this:

```
class A {
    public static String s = "a";
    public static String f() { 
        return s;
    } 
}

class B extends A {
    public static String s = "b"; 
}
```

Here, `A.f()` and `B.f()` will both return "a".

So: if you can't inherit a static method, then you can't override it; and if you can't override it, then making it abstract would be pointless.